# Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS update problems sudo apt-get update

Tags: apt, updates, wine

Hello i have a problem with new update in ubuntu can someone help me 
i have this error

```
~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://si.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://si.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease             
Hit:3 http://si.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease           
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [83,2 kB]    
Get:5 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease [4689 B]       
Err:5 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease                
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 818A435C5FCBF54A
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 818A435C5FCBF54A
E: The repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you didn't import GPG keys when you added the `winehq` repository:

```
GPG error: https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 818A435C5FCBF54A
```

Try importing them with this command:

```
wget -qO- https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

and then do a `sudo apt-get update`.

The error should be gone.

Comment: wine dont work i cant launch it

Comment: @DJ84 that's another problem, you should ask another question